# Calculated Column Formula Field Count Numbers of days unles status = X

Tags: list, column, validation

We want to create a list of contracts currently underway. We have created a column with a calculated formula:

Time in progress =TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy")-Created

what we need to add to this formula is a validation to calculate the status column is NOT Contract Signed.

Help please with the second part Thx

LJ

Comment: If contract is not signed, the field will show the days. What do you want the calculated column to show if the contract is signed?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a calculated column named **TimeInProgress** that will show the final calculated value based on the formula. I have also added another Boolean(Yes/No) field named **Contact Signed** . If Contract Signed is YES the TimeInProgress value will be blank. Only if it is not signed(value= No), the calculated column will be populated. The formula used is :

```
=IF([Contract Signed],"",DATEDIF(Created,TODAY(),"d"))
```

**Output** :

[image]

**Calculated Column Formula :**

[image]

In case you want to show some text in the calculated column other than leaving it blank, you can update the formula as

```
=IF([Contract Signed],"SomeText",DATEDIF(Created,TODAY(),"d"))
```